# Generic permission manager pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

What I'm trying to do is to create a class with static methods to manage rights of different user types on some types of resources (which are NHibernate entity objects). Specifically I'd like to check the current principal (in an asp.net MVC project) against an object id, to see if he can view or edit an entity. The signature I have in mind is the following:

```
PermissionManager.CanView<TEntity>(object id);
```

By now I've done these steps:

1) an interface like this:

```
public interface ICanAccessQuery<TAccount, TEntity>
    where TAccount : IAccountOwner
{
    bool CanView(TAccount user, object entityKey);
    bool CanEdit(TAccount user, object entityKey);
}
```

2) some implementations like this one:

```
public class TeacherCanAccessCourseReportsQuery : ICanAccessQuery<Teacher, CourseReport>
{
    public bool CanView(Teacher user, object entityKey)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<CourseReport>(x => x.Id == (long)entityKey);

        var conditions = PredicateBuilder.Create<CourseReport>(x => x.Teacher.Id == user.Id);
        conditions = conditions.Or(x => x.Teacher.Tutor.Id == user.Id);
        conditions = conditions.Or(x => x.CoachingTeachers.Any(t => t.Id == user.Id));

        predicate = predicate.And(conditions);

        return RepositoryProvider.Get<CourseReport>().Count(predicate) > 0;
    }

    public bool CanEdit(Teacher user, object entityKey)
    {
        // similar implementation
    }
}
```

3) a static Configure() method inside my PermissionManager class, to be called in Global.asax:

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> _permissions = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public static void Configure()
{
    _permissions.Add(typeof(Teacher).Name + typeof(CourseReport).Name, new TeacherCanAccessCourseReportsQuery());
}
```

4) inside the PermissionManager class:

```
public static bool CanView<TEntity>(object primaryKey, params string[] enabledRoles)
{
    var accounts = RepositoryProvider.Get<Account, AccountRepository>();
    var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as MyCustomPrincipal;

    if (enabledRoles.Any(r => principal.IsInRole(r)))
        return true;

    IAccountOwner user = accounts.GetUser(principal.AccountId);

    var can = false;
    var @switch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
            { typeof(Teacher), () => can = CanView<Teacher, TEntity>(user as Teacher, primaryKey) },
            { typeof(TrainingCenter), () => can = CanView<TrainingCenter, TEntity>(user as TrainingCenter, primaryKey) }
    };

    @switch[user.GetType()]();

    return can;
}

private static bool CanView<TAccount, TEntity>(TAccount user, object primaryKey)
        where TAccount : IAccountOwner
{
    var key = typeof(TAccount).Name + typeof(TEntity).Name;
    if (_permissions.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return (((ICanAccessQuery<TAccount, TEntity>)_permissions[key]).CanView(user, primaryKey);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The same methods would be defined for CanEdit... perfectly identical except the method name to be called.

What I'm asking is: is there a better way to define what I have in mind, in a more OOP-way?

Comment: If you restrict `TAccount` to `IAccountOwner`, you could use `IAccountOwner` directly. And I don't really like the idea of using `object primaryKey`. You could use an object of type `TEntity` directly. Maybe `TEntity` could be an interface `IHasAPrimaryKey` which you then could use directly and completely get rid of generics. Not that they're bad, quite the opposite, but they feel a bit unnecessary here (IMHO). Also, using a `string` as the key for `_permissions` could probably be improved by using a `Tuple<Type, Type>` or something similar.

Comment: And the `@switch` dictionary could probably be declared outside the `CanView` method, so it doesn't need to be created every time.

Comment: Ah, but without the generics, you lose the polymorphy. I see.

Comment: My primary goal was to create a system as generic as possible, with only the `ICanAccessQuery` implementations and the `PermissionManager` class itself as concrete classes. But maybe I don't know OOP to much to design such a thing. The result above required two days and I'm not satisfied of it :) thanks for replying anyway!

Comment: A little note on the side: never use `.Count(predicate) > 0`, use `.Any(predicate)` instead. You don't actually need to count the results, you only need to know if there are any. For performance reasons, don't do unnecessary work.

Comment: You are sending a query to the database to check a condition between the user and some entity. If the condition is OK, you send a second query to the database, to fetch that entity. Why not send only one query, that includes the condition, to fetch the entity? If the entity is returned, the condition was met (meaning the user has access). If no entity is returned, that means it either doesn't exist, or the user has no permission to see it. That would not only be much more efficient, it would also be a lot easier to develop.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I think I'll change the system this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a better solution  that maybe can be interesting for someone.

This is the interface of a "Can I access?" query:

```
public interface ICanAccessQuery<TAccount, TEntity>
    where TAccount : IAccountOwner
    where TEntity : IStoredEntity
{
    bool CanView(TAccount user, TEntity entity);
    bool CanEdit(TAccount user, TEntity entity);
}
```

My entities now implement an empty interface `IStoredEntity` to make a constraint.

And this is an example of implementation:

```
public class TeacherCanAccessOrdersQuery : ICanAccessQuery<Teacher, Order>
{
    public bool CanView(Teacher user, Order entity)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Order>(x => x.Id == entity.Id && x => x.Account.Id == user.Account.Id);
        return RepositoryProvider.Get<Order>().Count(predicate) > 0;
    }

    public bool CanEdit(Teacher user, Order entity)
    {
        // similar implementation
    }
}
```

Finally, my new `AuthorizationProvider` class (changed name from PermissionManager, didn't like it):

```
public class AuthorizationProvider
{
    public enum Abilities
    {
        View,
        Edit
    };

    private static IDictionary<string, object> _authorizations = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // this method should be called at application bootstrap, such as Global.asax in an asp.net app
    public static void Configure()
    {
        _authorizations.Add(typeof(Teacher).Name + typeof(CourseReport).Name, new TeacherCanAccessCourseReportsQuery());
        _authorizations.Add(typeof(Teacher).Name + typeof(Order).Name, new TeacherCanAccessOrdersQuery());
        // other rules user type-entity type
    }

    // Can I view entity with primary key X?
    public static bool CanI<TEntity>(Abilities ability, object entityKey)
        where TEntity : IStoredEntity
    {
        TEntity entity = RepositoryProvider.Get<TEntity>().Load(entityKey);
        return CanI<TEntity>(ability, entity, AccountRoles.Admin);
    }

    // Can I view entity (and if I have a specific role, I surely can)?
    public static bool CanI<TEntity>(Abilities ability, TEntity entity, params string[] authorizedRoles)
        where TEntity : IStoredEntity
    {
        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as MyCustomPrincipal;

        if (authorizedRoles.Any(r => principal.IsInRole(r)))
            return true;

        var user = RepositoryProvider.Get<Account, AccountRepository>().GetUser(principal.AccountId);

        // my system has only two types of users
        if (user is Teacher)
        {
            return Can<Teacher, TEntity>(user as Teacher, ability, entity);
        }
        else if (user is TrainingCenter)
        {
            return Can<TrainingCenter, TEntity>(user as TrainingCenter, ability, entity);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// Can user X (view|edit) entity Y?
    /// With some reflection I call the needed method. In this way I can add "abilities" to my ICanAccessQuery
    /// interface and its implementations without altering this class.
    public static bool Can<TAccount, TEntity>(TAccount user, Abilities ability, TEntity entity)
        where TAccount : IAccountOwner
        where TEntity : IStoredEntity
    {
        var key = typeof(TAccount).Name + typeof(TEntity).Name;
        if (_authorizations.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var query = (ICanAccessQuery<TAccount, TEntity>)_authorizations[key];
            string methodName = "Can" + ability.ToString();

            var method = typeof(ICanAccessQuery<TAccount, TEntity>).GetMethod(methodName);
            return (bool)method.Invoke(query, new object[] { user, entity });
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

An example of use in an asp.net mvc controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(long? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return new EmptyResult();

    if (!AuthorizationProvider.CanI<CourseReport>(AuthorizationProvider.Abilities.View, id.Value))
        return RedirectToAccessDenied();

     // etc.
}
```